# HQL restriction on child collection

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql

I have a class which has a collection

```
public class Parent
{
    ...
    ISet<Child> Children;
    ...
}
```

Given a list of child names, I'd like to return parents whose Children property contains all items of this list.

I managed to write an HQL query, but it works for a single name, not a whole list :

```
SELECT p FROM Parent AS p JOIN p.Children AS c WHERE c.Name = 'MyName'
```

Comment: IIRC you'll need division to do that ( http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/ ) This might help: http://forum.castleproject.org/viewtopic.php?t=5164 http://forum.castleproject.org/viewtopic.php?p=15157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Mauricio, I managed to solve this problem with the following criteria query

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Parent>("p")
                        .Add(Restrictions.IsNotEmpty("p.Children"));

foreach (var name in namesToMatch)
{
     criteria.Add(Subqueries.Exists(DetachedCriteria.For<Parent>("p2")
                            .SetProjection(Projections.Id())
                            .CreateAlias("p2.Children", "c")
                            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.Name", name))
                            .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("p2.Id", "p.Id"))));
}
```